# TwiML containing S3 signed URL gives error in voice call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am trying to invoke the following:

```
twilio api:core:calls:create \
    --method GET \
    --url https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/play?job=1589297170910&record=2&username=992b512f-130d-4da6-a9d3-a1a4227f82f5 \
    --to +19995551212 \
    --from +12345678901

SID                                 From          To            Status  Start Time
CA283a5deadbeefcafe0c89e861d  +12345678901  +19995551212  queued  null
```

The endpoint in the `--url` parameter above returns TwiML, with a response like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Apigw-Requestid: M8x5Wgf9IAMEVmg=
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1154
Content-Type: text/xml
Date: Fri, 22 May 2020 20:04:12 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play>https://s3.amazonaws.com/<my bucket name>/private/jobs/992b512f-130d-4da6-a9d3-a1a4227f82f5/1589297170910/2.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIA23STQFMZWXGL6GU2&Signature=3trMYp%2Fzc6ZV4FNRUc6%2B2Exen3k%3D&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEPT%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDJyUkf%2FBrHEVBl2k3rKHpaAwyaObsObFqTxp53P%2FKghQIgHPH8Idf9cGZ4XR9zxbs%2FgbEuPmeOPO3%2FbNQQP%2F6LOf8q8QEITRAAGgw3NDY0MjU2OTA5MzEiDBK45eAIlYDHS04WHirOASI41mSxg6kEefiyQkZ969RopMhCFBdsXrUZWefUHrRqkFL209n%2BNLV0gKhAmyG8vvlRON74Zy3J05aIQ79%2BxFwYfKq9HLhvFskU%2B58Q8QmZlZtiPQ0KSGI2OuMceXaroRlVdfEBUJgMwR0EoXYGbf9XlXLgbK8%2BpLLtQ7MNAE4bTNE1%2FccQgq33s1wZfKyUKQGjeZkZEU2ISvDCvvUTsRgLMT9zM1thLszgm7eoaKv%2BdnfeFTKAEQDNaIFtGUwAihm5yaW6XphY8sUtccJoMLvgoPYFOuABojlUjGBEbxcXkk6nIMs6f1KYxc6USarhca13DgbrGnTdGG0CeD3KW9OByw2Cv6A7gyfAgAjSBzDyfC%2FScaYs6i4WdnZNO190d%2F3PoPMnL2kcxqRiWDo9lVXqGa03RekFKWgJGxxZ2nUXffBw9twDmZ%2BElVOZv2M2lhxOR8f06JbX3BtP0%2BE5RNxpRx0HUxeakZzrOcSqpS9OEESYB0E4UtOzrSqPJ0K7V%2B%2FhOldIoAyv%2Bdce1TZgrjgyMMjxemxQeKrtW7RSlXLh2S3SGtN7O2eg06h4YkoikzSWXsmfAOw%3D&Expires=1590782652</Play>
</Response>
```

The URL in the  element above is an Amazon S3 signed URL for an MP3 file. It works fine if played directly in the browser. It also has the proper MIME type set for an MP3 file — `audio/mpeg`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 19010
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Date: Fri, 22 May 2020 20:08:52 GMT
ETag: "68e63d2845abc6ed528445ab22de68f6"
Last-Modified: Fri, 22 May 2020 19:32:48 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2: M/ic62y1nbUEn4PA1THXqx4rdEpKV70C8L6EifAlREOnf7CaG+frpICoaStqn9fr4T9saEJu9qk=
x-amz-request-id: 118DFC99C7EA2F66
[...binary data truncated...]
```

When I receive my phone call, the message played is "We are sorry, an application error has occurred." I can't find any more debug info.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there an issue with using querystrings or urlencoded strings?

Answer (score 1):

I failed to XML-encode my TwiML `<Play>` contents. A simple string replace from `&` to `&amp;`.